# Does Going Super Saiyan Raise Intelligence?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

Is there any record of this? I would think that this would be part of the package as it would make the Saiyan more strategic etc.

The first time Goku becomes a Super Saiyan he seems to get more stoic, and possibly more intelligent but is there concrete proof that his intelligence also increased (or any Saiyan going Super Saiyan for that matter)?

Comment: It's highly debatable as going up in Saiyan level causes raise in power level thus more entropy, which might cause less focus on one's actions. But again, if one becomes more conscious of power level (Ki), then it again is possible that one becomes smarter.

Answer (score 8):

Officially there is no such information provides as far as I'm aware.

Considering the anime DragonBall Z and the sequel DragonBall GT I would say: **No**, going Super Saiyan does not raise intelligence. Different Super Saiyans make a lot of unstrategic and plain stupid choices throughout the series.

**Example 1**: Gohan is most likely the most intelligent Saiyan in the series, considering his love for studies and hatred for fighting. In the Cell Saga, after turning Super Saiyan 2, he trades intelligence and strategic, rational thinking for arrogance and power. Instead of finishing off Cell, he plays with him until Cell starts his self destruct sequence, leading to the (or "a") death of Goku.

**Example 2**: Gotenks. You could say it is because he is the fusion of two kids, but Super Saiyan 3 Gotenks wastes the victory over Buu, leading to his absorption.

**Example 3**: In DragonBall GT Vegeta and Goku fuse into Super Saiyan 4 Gogeta to fight Omega Shenlong. This ultimate version of Gogeta, the strongest fighter in the universe, uses funny moves instead of finishing off the enemy, until the fusion time is up and Goku and Vegeta split.

**Example 4**: In DragonBall Z's Buu Saga, Super Saiyan Goku and Super Saiyan Vegeta engage in their long awaited duel, ignoring warning and causing the release of Buu.

All in all it would seem that the Super Saiyan transformation increases the ferocious, wild and animalistic tendencies of Saiyans, their basic instincts. They go into "combat mode" and solve their problems by force instead of talking things out. Not very intelligent nor strategic.

Comment: The only example I can think of of a super-saiyan that has been able to avoid making arrogance-based mistakes is future-Trunks, who seems to retain his focus on defeating, rather than toying with an enemy.

Comment: @sequoiad to be fair, he was also the one who though to have surpassed his father with the "Super Saiyan 1.5 over-the-limit" thing that increased raw power **at price of speed** ... only to discover later that Vegeta knew too but also knew it would have been almost worthless to use against Cell.